# CSS help - links color

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink

I have a problem with my CSS, when I'm trying to make links on my page, another color, when you put the mouse over it. The problem is, that I have 2 pages, and it works in one, but I can't get it to work in the other one. I have no idea why it is not working? Anyone have any idea?

I'm using this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  font-weight: {bold}
  A:link {text-decoration: bold; font-weight:bold}
  A:visited {text-decoration: bold; font-weight:bold}
  A:hover {color: #F91B27; text-decoration: bold}
  A:active {text-decoration: bold; font-weight:bold}
</style>
```

Comment: Have you linked to the css file in both pages?  Are your references correct (ie relative references can be tricky at times)?  What is the css like in your other page?  Something might be overriding your rules here.  More info needed pls.

Comment: Plus font-weight:{bold} doesn't look right to me..  Font weight is not a selector.

Comment: First line isn't a valid CSS rule. `bold` is a valid value of `font-weight` but not of `text-decoration`. `none` and `underline` would be

Comment: Give us more details and we can better help you.

Comment: And is this in both pages?  Also, your css is still wrong (see above comments)

Comment: You have some invalid CSS as the others have pointed out. As Mat said I would check your styles in the other page make sure the CSS file is loaded. Can you provide more background on this?

Comment: Did you attach the CSS from the correct path? Does the link direct somewhere?

Comment: Okay, i'll try to give you some more detail. First of all, i'm trying to get this to work on all links on my pages, and i have a Weebly page. So i'm not using any htlm, links are build into weebly. Sorry Varitomiranda, if that's now what you are saying..

I tried to create an almost identical page to the one i'm having the problem with, and in this is it working.

Will it help if you get the entire CSS of the page? I'm kinda new to this, and danish, so i tried to do as you told, not sure if it is correct?

Comment: <style type="text/css">

font-weight: {bold}

A:link {text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold}

A:visited {text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold}

A:active {text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold}

a:hover {color: #F91B27; font-weight: bold}

</style>

Comment: Now i even tried to copy the entire CSS into another page, and it's working here! So it can't be something overwriting, because it's working perfectly on a new side, with exactly the same css..

Comment: My be an `!important` CSS is overwritting your previously declared CSS. Use "Inspect Element" in Chrome or "FireBug" in Firefox, or "DragonFly" in Opera to inspect the anchors in HTML to get their CSS to check whether a repeated CSS overlaps the previous one.

Comment: I don't know quite how to do this, but i already tried to delete a lot of my CSS to see if it would work if a certain part was gone, and the weird thing is that the exact same CSS works if i start a new site.

Comment: Oh wait, it's working now! I just found out that Weebly already provide this feature, without editing the CSS, maybe that's the reason why it wasn't working. But anyways, thanks for the help everybody! :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first answer... "look at the path" however if that does not work I would suggest you perform a simple test (it has always helped me to do stuff separately) doing a simple test always works for me, look... you need to do this:

1. Create simple css file with just the code you want:

   ```
   font-weight: {bold}
   a:link {text-decoration: bold; font-weight:bold}
   a:visited {text-decoration: bold; font-weight:bold}
   a:hover {color: #F91B27; text-decoration: bold}
   a:active {text-decoration: bold; font-weight:bold}
   ```
2. Create a test page "With Out" referencing this css:

   Page Without CSS  

   Without CSS  no css
3. Create a second page (this will be [page1].html) that will add the reference to your css file:

Comment 1: Please Note that myCss is the name of the css file you created 
Comment 2: in the href you need to replace with the file's current location
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_href.asp

```
<html>
<head> 
<title> Page Referencing Css </title> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCss.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<a href="#"> link one </a>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Repeat step 3, but name the page different to create a second page ([page2].html)
2. Put all files inside a unique folder.
3. Now, perform a simple test by opening all files and determine if the css is applied to the  tags or not.
4. If this worked, then compare this test to what you are doing in your current project.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have tried to write some new info in the comments :)